# Unexpected behavior using By Ref with Reference type Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, pass-by-reference, ref, reference-type

Experienced an unexpected behavior when using Dictionary type and passing by reference.
Within a nested call, the reference to the underlaying base dictionary seems to be lost or replaced.
All child method calls are passing the dictionary by ref.

```
public void Main() {
   // Get Dictionary and fill if empty - Type 1 Dictionary
   Dictionary<string, string> dictStored = DictionaryFetch(1);
   
   // Pull from previously filled and stored static dictionary
   dictStored = DictionaryFetch(1);
}
```

My understanding is that I am passing the address reference of the local type (which itself is a reference type object - Dictionary).
If a dictionary is assigned on the child method that action occurs on the parent dictionary (meaning its the same object, same memory address ref).

Within `DictionaryFetch()`, if the dictionary is empty and needs to be created, the final switch..case assignment to the static dictionary should not be required. I would like to remove this final reassignment to the root static dictionary.

```cs
// Method to find and return the correct Dictionary by Type.
void DictionaryFetch(int DictType)
{
    
  Dictionary<string, string> localDict = new();
    
  // Retrieve Dict pass by reference  
  // localDict will contain static dictA or dictB contents
  DictionaryFetchStatic(dictType, ref localDict);

  // Check dictionary, create if empty
  if (localDict.Count == 0)
  {
     // Method to populate localDict with entries.
     CreateDictionary(ref localDict);  
         
     // Here is the gotcha, the static dictA or dictB is still empty, 
     // but localDict is populated - hence the need for the following switch statement
     switch(dictType)
     {             
        case 1:                
             dictA = localDict;
             break;                
        case 2:                
             dictB = localDict;
             break;
     };
   }
   return localDict;
}
```

What am I missing? Why is the dictA not populated before the final switch..case statement in `DictionaryFetch()`?

```cs
static Dictionary<string, string> dictA = new();
static Dictionary<string, string> dictB = new();

void DictionaryFetchStatic(int dictType, ref Dictionary<string, string> dictRequester)
{
    switch(dictType)
    {             
        case 1:                
            dictRequester = dictA;
            break;                
        case 2:                
            dictRequester = dictB;
            break;
    };
}

void CreateDictionary(ref Dictionary<string, string> dictRequester)
{
    // Just an example of creating a dictionary using DbContext, its generating a new Dict in response.
    dictRequester = _context.owner.Where(x => x.type == 'abc')
           .ToDictionary(o => o.key, o => o.value);
}
```

Comment: filldictmethod always destoys its callers dicionary and loads it from _context.owner, so all the fancy dicta or dictb stuff gets overwritten

Comment: @pm100 localDict is populated after the response from FillDictMethod,  but the static dictA / dictB root dictionary is not.  If the dictRequester(passed by ref) was destroyed, then the localDict in DictControllerMethod should be empty.

Comment: Side note: naming is hard. You should not name the method that creates a new dictionary as "Fill" - this is confusing as it *sounds* like the method is adding elements to the existing dictionary, while code explicitly notes that it does not do that "its generating a new Dict".

Comment: You're assigning a new reference (address) in `FillDictMethod`.  Your reference will no longer point to `dictA`. If you want it to work as expected, fill the current reference with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helpful response tips.
In my real-world scenario the fill method will use a DbContext and will generate a **new** very large dictionary.

The solution is to avoid use of local scope defined dictionary var, instead define a **ref dictionary** within DictControllerMethod().  This avoids the [pointer to a pointer] issue as reported in my question - just using and passing a single pointer to the root dictionary.

Its use of local defined dictionary vars that cause the unnecessary additional layers. The use of a reference-type[dictionary] by value added to the confusion.

```
public void Main() {

   int dictionaryType = 1; 

   // Get Dictionary and fill if empty - Type 1 Dictionary
   Dictionary<string, string> dictStored = DictionaryFetch(dictionaryType);
   

   // Pull from previously filled and stored static dictionary
   dictStored = DictionaryFetch(dictionaryType);
}
```

Methods:

```
static Dictionary<string, string> dictA = new();
static Dictionary<string, string> dictB = new();

ref Dictionary<string, string>  DictionaryFetchStatic(int dictionaryType)
{
    switch(dictionaryType)
    {             
        case 1:                
            return dictA;
        case 2:                
            return dictB;            
    };
}

// Method to find and return the correct Dictionary by Type.
Dictionary<string, string> DictionaryFetch(int dictionaryType)
{   
  // localDict will point to static dictA or dictB Dictionary reference type.
  ref Dictionary<string, string> localDict = ref DictionaryFetchStatic(dictionaryType);

  // Check dict, create if empty
  if (localDict.Count == 0)
  {
     // Method to fill localDict with entries.
     CreateDictionary(ref localDict);           
   
   }
   return localDict;
}

void CreateDictionary(ref Dictionary<string, string> dictRequester)
{
    // Just an example of filling a dictionary using DbContext, its generating a new Dict in response.
    dictRequester = _context.owner.Where(x => x.type == 'abc')
           .ToDictionary(o => o.key, o => o.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a new reference (address) in `FillDictMethod`. Your reference will no longer point to `dictA`.

If you want it to work as expected you'll need to mutate the `ref` variable and not just reassign it to point somewhere else.

```
static void FillDictMethod( ref Dictionary<string, string> dictRequester )
{
    // Add the values to the dictionary pointed to
    // by dictRequester.
    dictRequester.TryAdd( "Test", "Test" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @WBuck, in my real world scenario the dictionary is populated by a DbContext, therefore it will result in a new reference-type dictionary.  I think i've identified the optimal way of handling this within my answer - but i'm open to improvements.  Whats happening "under the hood" with types in C# can be sometimes be allusive.

Comment: @PeterOBrien same thing would happen in `C++` for the record.